# Adding a custom network to MetaMask with http address isn't working using wallet_addEthereumChain

Tags: reactjs, web3js, metamask

I am creating a button that adds a custom network to MetaMask. The issue is the geth node has an http address not a https. When I run the code to add with wallet_addEthereumChain I get an error saying it expects an https address. Is there a way around this.

```
    const formattedChainId = hexStripZeros(BigNumber.from(chainId).toHexString());
       try {
       await window.ethereum.request({
            method: "wallet_addEthereumChain",
            params: [
                 {
                    chainId: formattedChainId,
                    chainName: "CU Internal",
                    rpcUrls: ["http://myAddress"],
                    nativeCurrency: {
                      name: "ETH",
                      symbol: "ETH",
                      decimals: 18,
                         },
                    blockExplorerUrls: null,
                },
               ],
              });
             } catch (error) {
        console.error("error adding eth network: ");
        }
        }
```

This is the call I'm making

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, rpcUrls MUST be https, Metamask makes this check.

```
const firstValidRPCUrl = Array.isArray(rpcUrls)
    ? rpcUrls.find((rpcUrl) => validUrl.isHttpsUri(rpcUrl))
    : null;
```

but specification is

> All URL strings MUST include the protocol component of the URL. HTTPS SHOULD always be used over HTTP.